# How do I make different texts to appear in after clicking x-times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I want to show some text within a class for each click but keep the clicky-class. Shortly, if you click 2 times, you will get a div-text "You clicked two times", you will still be able to click a third time, then you will get "You clicked three times", until the fifth time when everything will hide. Is there any simpel way to do this? I tried with this but couldn't get it to work.

```
var clicks = 0;
$('.clicky').on('click', function()
    {
    clicks++;
        if(clicks >= 3)
        {
        $(this).add($('.background')).add($('.hello'));
        }

        else(clicks >= 5)
        {
        $(this).add($('.background')).hide();
        }
        });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLAzY/
This is a working example of the hide function.

Hope you understand what I mean
Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm confused. You say in your question that you want to change the text to display how many times the div was clicked, but in your code you aren't even attempting to change/set any text.

Comment: One problem with your code is `else(clicks >= 5)` which should read `else if (clicks >= 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you. I used JQuery data() instead of a global variable. So this will help you to have multiple elements of clicky class.

```
<div class="clicky">
    aaaa 
</div>
<div class="clicky">
    bbbb
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clicky').data('times', 0);
$('.clicky').on('click', function(){
    var times = parseInt($(this).data('times')) + 1;
    $(this).data('times', times);
    if( times >= 3 && times<5)
        $(this).addClass('background').addClass('hello');
    else if (times >= 5){
        $(this).hide('fast');
    }
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement. Note, because your elements only have class attributes the selectors can match multiple elements. Just something to keep in mind.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLAzY/1/) for testing

```
var clicks = 0;
$('.clicky').on('click', function(){
    var string;
    clicks++;
    switch(clicks){
    case 1:
        string = "You clicked one time";
        $('.clicky').text(string);
        break;
    case 2:
        string = "You clicked two times";
        $('.clicky').text(string);
        break;
    case 3:
        string = "You clicked three times";
        $('.clicky').text(string);
        break;
    case 4:
        string = "You clicked four times";
        $('.clicky').text(string);
        break;
    case 5:
        $(this).add($(".background")).hide();
        break;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it worked fine. If I want to change the strings to divs I simply change the case to: 
        `case 4:
        $('.clicky').text;
        break;` Right?

Comment: No. To change the strings to divs, you need to call `$('.clicky').html(string)` or else your tags will be converted to [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)